# How to break out of read loop in pipeline consumer

Tags: bash, shell, cat, read

I have this mini script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


do_tests(){
  # todo
}


go run . | (
    while read line; do
      if [[ "$line" == "listening" ]]; then
        do_tests  # run this once!
        break;
      fi
    done
)
```

what I want to do is to flip a boolean so that I don't run the tests more than 1x if there are multiple matching lines.

this is the only way I can think of doing it:

```
go run . | (

    while read line; do
      if [[ "$line" == "listening" ]]; then
        do_tests 
        break;
      fi
    done

    cat # run cat here
)
```

is there another way?

Comment: yes, there is. `go run . | tee >(grep -q listening && do_tests; cat >/dev/null)`. With GNU tee, you can also do `.. | tee --output-error=exit-nopipe >(grep -q listening && do_tests)`.

Comment: That, assuming that you want to let the data flow through your "consumer", which is NOT clear at all from the Q.

Comment: What @mosvy said.  Why do you have `cat` in the second example, but not in the first?

Comment: because cat will keep the consumer alive? maybe I need `exit` instead of `break` to make it correct